How to configure ESLint with Prettier and TypeScript on Node 20?
I tried to configure Prettier with ESLint and create a configuration in settings.json to fix errors when saving, but the errors appear in .js files and not in .ts files. How to configure this?
Dependencies:

"@eslint/js": "^9.4.0"
"prettier": "^3.3.0"
"typescript-eslint": "^7.11.0"
"eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0"
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3"

.prettierrc file:
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "semi": true,
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": "*.ts",
      "options": {
        "parser": "typescript"
      }
    }
  ]
}

eslint.config.mjs file:
import globals from 'globals';
import pluginJs from '@eslint/js';
import tseslint from 'typescript-eslint';
import eslintPluginPrettierRecommended from 'eslint-plugin-prettier/recommended';

export default [
  {
    languageOptions: {
      globals: globals.node,
    },
    rules: {
      camelcase: 'error',
      quotes: ['warn', 'single'],
      indent: ['error', 2, { SwitchCase: 1 }],
      'comma-dangle': ['error', 'always-multiline'],
      'max-len': ['error', { code: 120 }],
      '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'error',
      '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
      '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': [
        'error',
        { argsIgnorePattern: '^_' },
      ],
      '@typescript-eslint/quotes': [
        'error',
        'single',
        { allowTemplateLiterals: true },
      ],
      '@typescript-eslint/semi': ['error', 'always'],
      '@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface': 'off',
      '@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment': 'off',
    },
  },

  pluginJs.configs.recommended,
  ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
  eslintPluginPrettierRecommended,
];

.vscode/settings.json file:
{
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
  "[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
  "[javascriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.formatDocument": true,
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  },
  "editor.formatOnType": true
}

If the file is .js it shows ESLint errors normally but if it is .ts it shows nothing. Prettier and ESLint extensions are installed in VS Code.

Have you tried moving this block of code to the beginning of the code?
 pluginJs.configs.recommended,
 ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
 eslintPluginPrettierRecommended,

Because all those rules you wrote end up being about writing at the end.
Ex:
import globals from 'globals';
import pluginJs from '@eslint/js';
import tseslint from 'typescript-eslint';
import eslintPluginPrettierRecommended from 'eslint-plugin-prettier/recommended';

export default [
  pluginJs.configs.recommended,
  ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
  eslintPluginPrettierRecommended,
  {
    languageOptions: {
      globals: globals.node,
    },
    rules: {
      camelcase: 'error',
      quotes: ['warn', 'single'],
      indent: ['error', 2, { SwitchCase: 1 }],
      'comma-dangle': ['error', 'always-multiline'],
      'max-len': ['error', { code: 120 }],
      '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'error',
      '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
      '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': [
        'error',
        { argsIgnorePattern: '^_' },
      ],
      '@typescript-eslint/quotes': [
        'error',
        'single',
        { allowTemplateLiterals: true },
      ],
      '@typescript-eslint/semi': ['error', 'always'],
      '@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface': 'off',
      '@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment': 'off',
    },
  },
];

